# "Before" is to "ere", as "after" is to ...?

Tags: synonyms, archaicisms

Are there any literary, poetic, or archaic form of "after" or "beyond"?  I am especially interested in monosyllabic forms.

Both "aft" and "yon" won't work, because they have quite different meanings.

Comment: Can you please give an example sentence?

Comment: @sumelic "Ere the morning light broke" : "Before dawn" :: "___ the evening light dwindled" :  "After sunset". Is there a poetic, monosyllabic word, of the same tenor and quality as "ere", which could fill that blank? That's the answer sought.

Comment: @DanBron: I can think of examples myself, but of several different types. That's why I wanted Doubt to give an example. There are sentences like "After the storm, the sky grew bright"; (where "after" comes before a noun), "I will come here after this is done" (where it comes before a clause), and "The dog disappeared, and the man died soon after" (where it occurs without anything after it). There are synonyms that work in only some of these grammatical environments.

Comment: I don't get the close reason here. I think this is an interesting question ...

Comment: @DanBron Quite right. Simple question. Needs reopening. Have done the first reopen vote ...

Comment: @Araucaria: when asking for synonyms, that kind of thing is very relevant.

Comment: @Araucaria: it doesn't matter that "after" is the same part of speech when used in these different ways. It matters how the requested word is going to be used. When preceding a clause, Aml's answer of "when" or "once" often serves as a fine replacement for "after." "I will come here after/when/once this is done." Why was his answer downvoted? Maybe the downvoter was thinking that you can't say ""Once/when the storm, the sky grew bright" or "....and the man died soon once/when." But the original question never specifies in what contexts the words have to be interchangeable.

Comment: @Araucaria: So I don't know what criteria are supposed to be used when judging an answer, and the original poster seems to have abandoned the question.

Comment: @sumelic I would imagine that Aml's answer got downvoted because *when* and *once* are in no sense archaic, which is what OP was after. They are however monosyllabic, so it may have been worth the punt. Anyhow, not my downvote.

Comment: You could use *post* in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although their temporal separation is weaker, '**when**' and '**once**' are monosyllabic synonyms for 'after'.